# What's the name for the pop up logo/introduction image while software loads?

Tags: single-word-requests, software

The name is on the tip of my tongue.

What's the name for the pop up logo/introduction image while software loads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Splash Screen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen)

> A splash screen is a graphical control element consisting of window
>   containing an image, a logo and the current version of the software. A
>   splash screen usually appears while a game or program is launching.